# question about clickhouse ReplicatedMergeTree and Distributed ENGINE

Tags: clickhouse

Why ReplicatedMergeTree ENGINE didn't replica any data ?

I have three nodes to deploy ClickHouse,
I config a cluster with 3shard 2 replica, and I create a table with ReplicatedMergeTree ENGINE on all the three nodes, then I have inserted one row on one of the three nodes, I can only query data out from the node where I do insert, why? I've configured 2 more replicas, I think I should query out data from other nodes.

And if I create a table with Distributed ENGINE base on the table I created with ReplicatedMergeTree ENGINE, if I insert one row in it, I can query out two rows on the node where I do insert, but on other nodes sometimes I can query out one row sometimes I can query out nothing

Comment: May be the three nodes are not communicating with each other.That is why your data is not replicating in other two nodes. Try to put the host names of all the nodes including zookeeper nodes in the hosts.d file which is present in the /etc/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Related to Distributed Engine Table in CLickhouse.It sounds like everything is fine and you get half data from one server and full results (both halves) from the distributed table. You have put only half data to each shard, not the whole dataset.

Comment: thanks a lot , I Have 3 clickhouse nodes , and I config 3 shards , every shard have 2 replicas , I think this is the reason , because Every shard's replicas shuold not have the same IP address of other shard,right ?

Comment: Yes as because keeping the same replica on single shard server doesn't serve the purpose of true replication..So every replica must be different server i.e different Ip address.

Answer (score 0):

you may have the same problem as me here:

[Clickhouse shows duplicates data in distributed table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008231/clickhouse-shows-duplicates-data-in-distributed-table)

Solution: don't use circular cluster, or pay attention on how you create the tables