# Clickhouse shows duplicates data in distributed table

Tags: clickhouse

I have 3 nodes with 3 shards and 2 replicas on each:

​[CLickhouse cluster settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHBZD.png)

Added also the XML config for the sharding and replicas

```
<default_cluster>
   <shard>
      <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
      <replica>
         <default_database>shard</default_database>
         <host>clickhouse-0</host>
         <port>9000</port>
         <user>default</user>
         <password>default</password>
      </replica>
      <replica>
         <default_database>replica</default_database>
         <host>clickhouse-2</host>
         <port>9000</port>
         <user>default</user>
         <password>default</password>
      </replica>
   </shard>
   <shard>
      <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
      <replica>
         <default_database>shard</default_database>
         <host>clickhouse-1</host>
         <port>9000</port>
         <user>default</user>
         <password>default</password>
      </replica>
      <replica>
         <default_database>replica</default_database>
         <host>clickhouse-0</host>
         <port>9000</port>
         <user>default</user>
         <password>default</password>
      </replica>
   </shard>
   <shard>
      <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
      <replica>
         <default_database>shard</default_database>
         <host>clickhouse-2</host>
         <port>9000</port>
         <user>default</user>
         <password>default</password>
      </replica>
      <replica>
         <default_database>replica</default_database>
         <host>clickhouse-1</host>
         <port>9000</port>
         <user>default</user>
         <password>default</password>
      </replica>
   </shard>
</default_cluster>
```

I am doing the following example:

```
create database test on cluster default_cluster;

CREATE TABLE  test.test_distributed_order_local on cluster default_cluster
(
id integer,
test_column String
) 
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/default_cluster/test/tables/test_distributed_order_local/{shard}', '{replica}') 
PRIMARY KEY id
ORDER BY id;

CREATE TABLE  test.test_distributed_order on cluster default_cluster as test.test_distributed_order_local
ENGINE = Distributed(default_cluster, test, test_distributed_order_local, id);

insert into test.test_distributed_order values (1, 'test1');
insert into test.test_distributed_order values (2, 'test2');
insert into test.test_distributed_order values (3, 'test3');
```

The results are not the same, and they contain duplications: Eg

​[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwtel.png)

​[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0qM8.png)

​

What am I missing?

I expect to not have duplicated rows in the select

Comment: you need to set internal_replication=true, otherwise Distributed table may double rows because it multiplexes rows with internal_replication=false(default).

Comment: Added internal_replication=true on all shards, recreate all the tables, inserted new data, same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this post probably sums up what you're trying to achieve - https://altinity.com/blog/2018/5/10/circular-replication-cluster-topology-in-clickhouse
It's a little old but the principle applies - For Clickhouse  not a topology that's recommended.

Consider this simplified example:

```
<shard>
    // These two are replicas of each other
    <replica>
        <host>cluster_node_0</host>
    </replica>
    **<replica>
        <host>cluster_node_2</host>
    </replica>**
</shard>
<shard>
    <replica>
        <host>cluster_node_1</host>
    </replica>
    <replica>
        <host>cluster_node_0</host>
    </replica>
</shard>
<shard>
    **<replica>
        <host>cluster_node_2</host>
    </replica>**
    <replica>
        <host>cluster_node_1</host>
    </replica>
</shard>
```

Let's suppose data is written into the first shard on node `cluster_node_0`. It will then be replicated to the shard on `cluster_node_2` - as the zookeeper path is the same.

Now for the issue. You have also defined the 3rd shard on `cluster_node_2`. When you create this table, it will physically contain data from 2 shards - the 1st and 3rd - I've attempted to highlight with `**`.

When a query comes in, it will be sent to each shard. The challenge is each local table will respond with results from both shards - hence you get duplicates.

Generally, avoid more than one shard on a host - the blog explains how you can achieve more than one buts its not recommended or ever need.

Comment: tried to clarify as my initial explanation wasn't quite right

Comment: you're right! The problem is with the execution of DDL on shards. Each server contains two different shards but the macros are substituted only by one value.
Circle replication by Altinity is completely evil, it can be solved with a creation table with a hardcoded zookeeper path and server name manually on each shard/replica.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will try to avoid the circular replication cluster

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse show duplicates cause you use the same hosts in multiple shards

During execution of SELECT your query, it rewrites and execute in one replica in each shard.

Because same replica presents in different shards and query run twice.

Usually shard means data is not intersected between other shards

If you want a cluster for 3 shards and 2 replicas in each shard
You need 6 different replicas clickhouse-0..5

Comment: For the shard we are using different host, only for replica we are re-using the hosts for redundancy
Please see the added the configuration XML for cluster in the question

Comment: In the end, I managed to do it with 6 nodes, but Dale's answer contains more explanation. Thank you