# How to do Circular Replication On 4 Nodes 4 Shards 2 replica in Clickhouse?

Tags: database, replication, distribution, clickhouse

My Clickhouse configuration is as follows:

```
<remote_config_1>
            <shard>
            <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard1</default_database>
                    <host>node1.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard1</default_database>
                    <host>node2.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
            <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard2</default_database>
                    <host>node2.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard2</default_database>
                    <host>node3.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
            <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard3</default_database>
                    <host>node3.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard3</default_database>
                    <host>node4.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
            <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard4</default_database>
                    <host>node4.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <default_database>shard4</default_database>
                    <host>node1.dev.cluster</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <password>password</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
  </remote_config_1>
  
  
    <!-- NODE 1 -->

 <macros>
 <cluster01>circular_conf</cluster01>
 <shard01>s1</shard01>
 <shard02>s4</shard02>
 <replica01>n1_s1_r1</replica01>
 <replica02>n1_s4_r2</replica02>
 </macros>
 
   <!-- NODE 2 -->

  <macros>
 <cluster01>circular_conf</cluster01>
 <shard01>s2</shard01>
 <shard02>s1</shard02>
 <replica01>n2_s2_r1</replica01>
 <replica02>n2_s1_r2</replica02>
 </macros>
 
   <!-- NODE 3 -->

  <macros>
 <cluster01>circular_conf</cluster01>
 <shard01>s3</shard01>
 <shard02>s2</shard02>
 <replica01>n3_s3_r1</replica01>
 <replica02>n3_s2_r2</replica02>
 </macros>
 
   <!-- NODE 4 -->

  <macros>
 <cluster01>circular_conf</cluster01>
 <shard01>s4</shard01>
 <shard02>s3</shard02>
 <replica01>n4_s4_r1</replica01>
 <replica02>n4_s3_r2</replica02>
 </macros>
```

And I have created my tables on each node accordingly:

```
<!-- NODE 1 -->
CREATE TABLE shard1.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard01}/tables/hits', '{replica01}')
<!----- skipped order by----->
 
CREATE TABLE shard4.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard02}/tables/hits', '{replica02}')
<!----- skipped order by----->



<!-- NODE 2 -->
CREATE TABLE shard1.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard01}/tables/hits', '{replica01}')
<!----- skipped order by----->
 
CREATE TABLE shard2.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard02}/tables/hits', '{replica02}')
<!----- skipped order by----->


<!-- NODE 3 -->
CREATE TABLE shard2.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard01}/tables/hits', '{replica01}')
<!----- skipped order by----->
 
CREATE TABLE shard3.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard02}/tables/hits', '{replica02}')
<!----- skipped order by----->


<!-- NODE 4 -->
CREATE TABLE shard3.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard01}/tables/hits', '{replica01}')
<!----- skipped order by----->
 
CREATE TABLE shard4.sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster01}/{shard02}/tables/hits', '{replica02}')
<!----- skipped order by----->
```

And the distributed table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE distributed_sample_table
<!----- skipped table contents----->
ENGINE=Distributed('remote_config_1',
 '',
 'sample_table',
 rand());
<!----- skipped order by----->
```

After the creation of these tables I have inserted some data to distributed_sample_table. However whenever I run a query on distributed_sample_table I get different results. The amounts of the elements differ each time.
Where have I done wrong?
please help

Comment: Clickhouse does not support cluster circular replication:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008231/clickhouse-shows-duplicates-data-in-distributed-table